# Linking a textbox to a javascript equation ran by a button

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to put an input like 100, 45 into the textbox and run it through my equation via clicking the button and I cannot figure out how to do it. It should post the answer after clicking the button as an alert. Please Help. Thank you.

```js
function Rad(a, b){
    var Armor=a/(Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*b))
    alert(Armor)
}
```

```css
.box {
    color: gray;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.equation {
    color: #444;
    font: inherit;
    min-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <input class="equation" type="text">
  </div>
  <button onclick="Rad()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you haven't passed any parameters to `Rad()`. What are a and b?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: a and b ar the imput variables for the equation if the onclick function for the button is Rad(100, 45) it will read a as 100 and b as 45 and run it throught the equation.

Comment: I just cannot figure out how to link the text within the textbox to the two variables within the function and run it

Comment: This is what I don't get: I see a lot of these questions on SO and I undrstand that everyone likes to make fun stuff with javascript. But a lot of posters lack the fundamental basics and post questions that are easily solvable with basic knowledge, I guess they don't want to go through the boring stuff...My advice: go through the boring stuff and really learn the language it will bring you a lot further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Rad(a, b)` take 2 parameters.

To solve this you have to remove `onClick="Rad()"` because you don't pass any parameters here.

Make use of `jQuery` and **attach** a `click` event like below than **take value** from input and **split it** by `,` and call `Rad` with this 2 values.

```
$('#btnRad').click(function(){
    var equVal = $('.equation').val().split(',');
    Rad(equVal[0], equVal[1]);
});

function Rad(a, b){
    var Armor=a/(Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*b))
    alert(Armor)
}
```

HTML modified

```
<button id="btnRad">Click</button>
```

**Notes:** This way you can **reuse** the `Rad` function.

```js
function Rad(a, b){
    var Armor=a/(Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*b))
    alert(Armor)
}

$('#btnRad').click(function(){
  var equVal = $('.equation').val().split(',');
  Rad(equVal[0], equVal[1]);
  
  });
```

```css
.box {
    color: gray;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.equation {
    color: #444;
    font: inherit;
    min-height: 2em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <input class="equation" type="text">
  </div>
  <button id="btnRad">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

alter Rad function to be:

```
function Rad(){
    var inp=document.getElementById('eq'); // or document.getElementsByName('equation')[0]
    var splited=inp.value.split(',');
    var a=parseInt(splited[0],10);
    var b=parseInt(splited[1],10);
    var Armor=a/(Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*b))
    alert(Armor)
}
```

and don't forget to assign 'eq' as an id for input

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you haven't sent `a` and `b` to `Rad()`. If you are saying `a` and `b` are numbers inputted, separated by commas, then this will work:

If you want to send the two values entered to the function, you need to use Javascript again to get the value and call the function:

```js
function Rad(a, b) {
  var Armor = a / (Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * b))
  alert(Armor)
}

$('button').click(function() {
  Rad($('.equation').val().split(',')[0], $('.equation').val().split(',')[1]);
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.equation {
  color: #444;
  font: inherit;
  min-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <input class="equation" type="text">
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

This sends, to `Rad`, `a` and `b` begin the number before the comma and number after respectively.

eg: entering: `10, 20` will show: `29.238044001630875`

Comment: thanks this should work it's the site im running it on thanks

Answer (score 0):

This checks the input (which now has an `id`) matches "number,number" (with optional spaces), and pulls out those numbers before doing the math:

```js
function Rad() {
  var args = document.getElementById('args');
  var argstr = args.value;

  var matches = argstr.match(/^\s*([\d\.]+)\s*,\s*([\d\.]+)/);

  if (matches) {
    var a = +matches[1],
      b = +matches[2];

    var Armor = a / (Math.sin((Math.PI / 180) * b))
    alert(Armor)
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  color: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.equation {
  color: #444;
  font: inherit;
  min-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <input id="args" class="equation" type="text">
  </div>
  <button onclick="Rad()">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```